# windbg/sos: Finding which class has static reference to object

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg

I'm troubleshooting a memory leak and found that an object is being held in memory because it is referenced by a dictionary.  When I do a !gcroot on the dictionary instance, the only pinned handle is an array of System.Object[] which itself is unrooted:

```
0:025> !gcroot -nostacks 38ad01f8
DOMAIN(0000000002287D80):HANDLE(Pinned):11e15c0:Root:  00000000123c5018(System.Object[])->
  0000000002f2ab20(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[MyApp.MyObject, MyApp]])->
  000000004223e6e0(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[MyApp.MyObject, MyApp]][])->
  0000000038ad01f8(MyApp.MyObject)
```

This leads me to conclude that the Dictionary instance is being held by a static field on some class (.NET keeps all static field references in an Object array).

However, now I'm stuck because !gcroot and !refs (from sosex) do not see static field references.

I can search the heap for a pointer to the address 2f2ab20:

```
0:025> s-q 0 L?0xbfffffff 2f2ab20
00000000`123c76f8  00000000`02f2ab20 00000000`02f2ab78
```

So I see that some structure near the address 123c76f8 is referencing my dictionary. But where do I go from here? The structure near 123c76f8 must be pointed to by an EEClass structure, but sos/sosex don't seem to provide a way to resolve which EEClass is relevant.

Without that information, how can I figure out which object contains a static dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

One option for doing this sort of analysis is to use the ClrMD libraryon NuGet to write a small program to run over a dump or process.

The program would look like this:

```
    DataTarget dataTarget = DataTarget.LoadCrashDump(@"c:\path\to\crash.dmp");
    ClrRuntime runtime = dt.CreateRuntime(@"c:\path\to\mscordacwks.dll");
    ClrHeap heap = runtime.GetHeap();

    foreach (ClrRoot root in heap.EnumerateRoots())
    {
        if (root.Object == 0x0000000002f2ab20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(root.Kind);
            if (root.Kind == GCRootKind.StaticVar)
                Console.WriteLine(root.Name);
        }
    }
```

You can read more about the ClrMD library here on the [DotNet blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I run the code that is post on that [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2005/11/25/497016.aspx).

version:
Win7 X64 .NET 4

```
DOMAIN(000000000007E9D0):HANDLE(Pinned):1a17f8:Root:  0000000012381018(System.Object[])->
  0000000002391dc0(System.Collections.ArrayList)->
  0000000002391e78(System.Object[])->
  0000000002391e60(StaticRootedWhere.Fruit)



0:000> s-d 0000000012381018 L?0x2000 0000000002391dc0
00000000`12382fd8  02391dc0 00000000 0238fb30 00000000  ..9.....0.8.....


0:000> s-d 0 L?0xffffffffffffffff 00000000`12382fd8
00000000`00319680  12382fd8 00000000 02009443 00000000  ./8.....C.......
000007ff`000337d8  12382fd8 00000000 00000001 00000000  ./8.............
000007ff`00150160  12382fd8 00000000 24548b48 278ee828  ./8.....H.T$(..'




0:000> !u 000007ff`00150160
Normal JIT generated code
StaticRootedWhere.Program..cctor()
Begin 000007ff00150120, size 59

E:\..........\StaticRootedWhere\Program.cs @ 11:
000007ff`00150120 4883ec38        sub     rsp,38h
000007ff`00150124 48b8f0340300ff070000 mov rax,7FF000334F0h
000007ff`0015012e 8b00            mov     eax,dword ptr [rax]
000007ff`00150130 85c0            test    eax,eax
000007ff`00150132 7405            je      StaticRootedWhere!StaticRootedWhere.Program..cctor()+0x19 (000007ff`00150139)
000007ff`00150134 e817ac51ee      call    clr!JIT_DbgIsJustMyCode (000007fe`ee66ad50)
000007ff`00150139 488d0d58ff07ec  lea     rcx,[mscorlib_ni+0x4d0098 (000007fe`ec1d0098)]
000007ff`00150140 e81b2d0bee      call    clr!JIT_TrialAllocSFastMP_InlineGetThread (000007fe`ee202e60)
000007ff`00150145 4889442420      mov     qword ptr [rsp+20h],rax
000007ff`0015014a 488b442420      mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+20h]
000007ff`0015014f 4889442428      mov     qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax
000007ff`00150154 488b4c2428      mov     rcx,qword ptr [rsp+28h]
000007ff`00150159 e802b7f5eb      call    mscorlib_ni!System.Collections.ArrayList..ctor() (000007fe`ec0ab860)
000007ff`0015015e 48b9d82f381200000000 mov rcx,12382FD8h
000007ff`00150168 488b542428      mov     rdx,qword ptr [rsp+28h]
000007ff`0015016d e88e270bee      call    clr!JIT_WriteBarrier_Fast (000007fe`ee202900)
000007ff`00150172 eb00            jmp     StaticRootedWhere!StaticRootedWhere.Program..cctor()+0x54 (000007ff`00150174)
000007ff`00150174 4883c438        add     rsp,38h
000007ff`00150178 c3              ret
```

I post my result here just for your reference. this is my second time to verify the result after reading the blog. The first time verifying is not got the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

One method described [in this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2005/11/25/497016.aspx). A short explanation of the method is you want to locate a peice of code that added a new element into an object array. That object array is array of static fields (00000000123c5018 in your case). The name of the method is supposed to be AnOffendingType..ctor(), which is a static type constructor you are looking for.

Comment: I did come across that blog entry and tried to follow the steps, but unfortunately that blog was written in 2005 for .NET 1.1.  In .NET 2.0 the way MSIL accesses static fields evidently changed because when I search for references to 123c5018 I come up empty.

Comment: According to the blog you need to search for refeences to the location of the element inside the array, which is 123c76f8 in your case.

Comment: Right, I did that but pasted the wrong address in my comment. "s-q 0 L?0xbfffffff 123c76f8" also comes up empty, because .net 2.0 appears to use a helper function to locate static fields instead of just inlining them into the MSIL (e.g. CORINFO_HELP_ASSIGN_REF).  You can verify this by disassembling a method that assigns a reference to a static field.

Comment: Can you try one more thing -- search for 123c76f8 using byte alignment? The command is "s-b 0 L?0xbfffffff f8 76 3c 12". Since the address is part of the assembly instruction, it is not always Dword aligned (in 32 bit case) or Qword aligned (on 64 bits).

Comment: Tried that, zero hits.  I'm not sure if things are better in .NET 4 land, but if not I think I might report this edge case to Microsoft.  If !EEClass can show the values of static fields, there should be some command that traces a static field reference back to its owning EEClass structure.

Comment: Ok. I don't have any good ideas. But negative result is also a result -- at least now we know this method is not always working...